# Probability of extracting a certain subset from a set given K tries

Tags: probability

There are N balls. W of them are white, the rest of them are black.

You extract K balls, where W ≤ K ≤ N.

What's the probability that all of the white balls were extracted?

Comment: Hint: consider the case where $W\ge \frac{N}{2}$.

Comment: Try to do it for N=1, 2, 3, and see the pattern. (And use the product rule for the probabilities).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier way to see the problem.

Let $D = N-K$. What is the probability of extracting D black balls consecutively?

Probability of the first ball to be black $\times \cdots \times$ Probability of the $D$-th ball to be black:    $$P=\frac{N-W}{N} \cdot \frac{N-W-1}{N-1} \cdots \frac{N-W-D+1}{N-D+1} = \frac{(N-D)!(N-W)!}{N!(N-W-D)!} = \frac{K!(N-W)!}{N!(K-W)!}$$

Why are these two problems the same?

Extracting without replacement K balls is equivalent to arranging the N balls in a random sequence (BWWBBB) and picking the K first balls (BWWB).  We want the probability that the last N-K balls (BB) are black. Which means the problem is the same as picking N-K black balls at the end of the sequence (BB). In other words extracting N-K black balls consecutively.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is easy to follow and understand.